# Chartboost ad causes background music to pause in unity 3d android/ios app

Tags: c#, android, ios, unity-game-engine

I am working on my first mobile game which is mainly music based.

Whenever I show a chartboost interstital ad in my app(ios and android), the background music in my app pauses until the user closes the ad. Is there any way to change this behavior to keep background music playing while an add is shown(or possible never allow audio to be paused in unity or keep it playing during an application pause)?

I've tried searching all over, but couldn't find any info about this. Tried contacting chartboost support a few days ago, haven't herd a response yet either.

Any advice would be much appreciated ^_^